# Why would my Netty-based server respond differently to curl HTTP/2 prior knowledge requests and vegeta -h2c requests?

Tags: curl, netty, vegeta

I have a Netty 4.1-based server.  I have taken great care to make it be a well-behaved HTTP/2 citizen.  Part of this effort involves handling both so-called "prior knowledge" and upgrade-from-HTTP-1.1 scenarios.

I have tested my application using `curl --http2` (which will do an upgrade if necessary) and `curl --http2-prior-knowledge`.  It responds fine in both cases and does what I would expect.

Recently, I discovered [`vegeta`](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta/), a great little load test tool.  It has an `-h2c` option, which I believe does what `curl --http2-prior-knowledge` does (HTTP/2 without TLS and without doing an "upgrade me from HTTP 1.1 please" dance.

Nevertheless, when I hit my server with `vegeta attack` with the `-h2c` option, even using just one request (via `-rate=1/2s -duration=2s`), `vegeta` hangs, unable to read the body:

```
Error Set:
net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while reading body)
```

To my knowledge, `vegeta` is written in Go and therefore probably uses the Go `h2c` library.  `curl` uses `nghttp`.  If I handle `curl`'s HTTP/2-via-prior-knowledge request properly but `vegeta` has trouble with it, what does this mean?